# R and Github SSHKeys

Tags: github, rstudio, ssh-keys

Im having trouble getting the SSH Key to work. I enter the information for the key, copied and pasted directly from R Studio, and when i submit it it goes to the original screen and says no SSH key has been entered. How do I make this work?

I followed the instructions exactly as stated in our curriculum and expected to see the screen shown in our guide stating the key has been accepted